# How to trigger fadeInRight effect using angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like implement in typescript a trigger using fadeInRight animation.

I got it implement a trigger but fadeIn and fadeOut.

Could you please help me?

follow my code below:

```
trigger('fade', [
  state('in', style({
      opacity: 1
  })),
  state('out', style({
    opacity: 0
  })),
  transition('in => out', animate('0ms ease-out')),
  transition('out => in', animate('500ms ease-in'))
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ng-animate package for animation](https://github.com/jiayihu/ng-animate)

For trigger FadeInRight effect follow these steps.

1. Install npm package

   `npm install ng-animate --save`
2. Import `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your `app.module.ts` file

   `import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`
3. In your `component.ts` file import `@angular/animations` module and `ng-animate` module

   `import { trigger, transition, useAnimation } from '@angular/animations';

    import { bounce } from 'ng-animate';`
4. Your `ComponentName.ts`file in `@Component` meta data add the following code

   `animations: [
      trigger('fadeInRight', [transition('* => *', useAnimation(fadeInRight, {
        // Set the duration to 5seconds and delay to 2seconds
        params: { timing: 5, delay: 2 }
      }))])
   ]`
5. In your `ComponentName.html` file add following code

   `<h1 [@fadeInRight]="fadeInRight">Here FadeInRight animation working..</h1>`

Comment: but I would like implement "fade in right"and "fade in left"

Comment: @Andre, Sorry for late reply but these is really useful for you. its work as expected. if you have still issue issue then tell me i am glad to help you.

Comment: I'am very happy to helping you. Thanks @Andre

Comment: Thank you so much!